# How far before the job start date I can apply for a TN visa

Tags: usa, working-visas, tn-visa, nafta

I'm planning to apply for a TN visa at the US border. I'm accompanying my wife, and she is going to study in the US. We are going there a month and a half prior to my job start date and 2 weeks before the start date of her program, in order to settle down, find a place, etc.

Is it true that TN visa is issued only a week before the job start date? That seems very close to the job start date.

Comment: Just a note on the terminology: when you apply at the border, you are applying for admission in TN *status,* and you are entering the US with no visa whatsoever.  Strictly speaking, a visa is just a document, a sticker in your passport, and you won't have one.  This option is available only to citizens of Canada; Mexican citizens must apply for a visa in advance at a US consulate.